# Week-number calculation

Tags: pascal, week-number

I have a problem with code which used to calculate the week number from date.
The application is Report Builder.
The language is: Report Application Programming (RAP)The RAP language is identical to Object Pascal.

My written code works for the years 2017 and 2018.
But it doesn`t work for 2019 and 2020.

Does someone have an Idea what I´m doing wrong here?

```
if (AVX['P_DELDATE'] >= 42737) and (AVX['P_DELDATE'] <= 43100) {= Jahr        2017} then begin
Value:= (AVX['P_DELDATE'] - 1 - (42737-1) + 7-((AVX['P_DELDATE'] -1 - (42737-1) ) mod 7))/7;
end else begin

if (AVX['P_DELDATE'] >= 43101) and (AVX['P_DELDATE'] <= 43465) {= Jahr 2018} then begin
Value:= (AVX['P_DELDATE'] - 1 - (43101-1) + 7-((AVX['P_DELDATE'] -1 -  (43101-1) ) mod 7))/7;
end;
end else begin

if (AVX['P_DELDATE'] >= 43466) and (AVX['P_DELDATE'] <= 43830) {= Jahr  2019} then begin
Value:= (AVX['P_DELDATE'] - 1 - (43466-1) + 7-((AVX['P_DELDATE'] -1 - (43466-1) ) mod 7))/7;
end;
end else begin

if (AVX['P_DELDATE'] >= 43831) and (AVX['P_DELDATE'] <= 44196) {= Jahr 2020} then begin
Value:= (AVX['P_DELDATE'] - 1 - (43831-1) + 7-((AVX['P_DELDATE'] -1 - (43831-1) ) mod 7))/7;
end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Identical?  What does the function AVX return?  Btw, it would be more reliable to calculate the week number in Delphi code amd feed that into RB.

Comment: What specifically does *doesn't work for year 2019 and 2020* mean? There's no problem description here - *doesn't work* without any specifics is not a useful problem description.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say why you are asking about doing the Week number calculation
in RAP code.  Apart from the fact that I can find no definition of the `AVX`
function in the RAP documentation, attempting to calculate the week number
using `AVX` in RAP is obviously error-prone, not self-documenting and is an all but undebuggable way to do it.

Evidently, your function(?, or maybe it is a report field) `AVX` returns a numeric value whose integer part corresponds to the integer part of a TDateTime value.  In the example project 
below - which I have included to show a much easier and less error prone way
of dealing with the problem, I included a function which (I hope) matches your RAP function, as follows:

```
 function WeekNumber(Day : Integer) : Double;
begin
  if (Day >= 42737) and (Day <= 43100) {= Jahr        2017} then begin
      result:= (Day - 1 - (42737-1) + 7-((Day -1 - (42737-1) ) mod 7))/7;
  end
  else begin
    if (Day >= 43101) and (Day <= 43465) {= Jahr 2018} then begin
      result:= (Day - 1 - (43101-1) + 7-((Day -1 -  (43101-1) ) mod 7))/7;
    end
    else begin
      if (Day >= 43466) and (Day <= 43830) {= Jahr  2019} then begin
        result:= (Day - 1 - (43466-1) + 7-((Day -1 - (43466-1) ) mod 7))/7;
      end
      else begin
        if (Day >= 43831) and (Day <= 44196) {= Jahr 2020} then begin
          result:= (Day - 1 - (43831-1) + 7-((Day -1 - (43831-1) ) mod 7))/7;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

(Btw, in doing this conversion, I had to fix a number of syntax error in your RAP code which you'll soon find if you try the conversion yourself.)

Then, I added a procedure to test this function:

```
procedure TForm1.TestWeekNumber;
var
  Date : TDateTime;
  i : integer;

  procedure TestInner(Date : TDateTime);
  var
    WN1,
    WN2 : Double;
    S,
    SError : String;
  begin
    WN1 := WeekOf(Date);
    WN2 := WeekNumber(Trunc(Date));
    if WN1 = WN2 then
      SError := ''
    else
      SError := '***';
    S := Format('Date: %s WeekOf: %g WeekNumber: %g %s',[ DateTimeToStr(Date), WN1, WN2, SError]);
    if SError <> '' then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
  end;
begin
  Date := StrToDateTime('01/01/2017');
  Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := 0 to 1999 do
      TestInner(Date + i);
   finally
     Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
   end;
end;
```

This compares your `WeekNumber` with the standard `WeekOf` function in DateUtils.Pas, which returns the week number as defined by the ISO 8601 standard, of a TDateTime input value and writes the values to a TMemo when they produce different results.  The following is an extract from the output:

```
Date: 01/01/2017 WeekOf: 52 WeekNumber: 1.13989900694441E-307 ***
Date: 31/12/2018 WeekOf: 1 WeekNumber: 53 ***
Date: 07/01/2019 WeekOf: 2 WeekNumber: 1 ***
Date: 14/01/2019 WeekOf: 3 WeekNumber: 2 ***
Date: 21/01/2019 WeekOf: 4 WeekNumber: 3 ***
Date: 28/01/2019 WeekOf: 5 WeekNumber: 4 ***
Date: 04/02/2019 WeekOf: 6 WeekNumber: 5 ***
Date: 11/02/2019 WeekOf: 7 WeekNumber: 6 ***
[...]
Date: 06/01/2020 WeekOf: 2 WeekNumber: 1 ***
Date: 07/01/2020 WeekOf: 2 WeekNumber: 1 ***
Date: 13/01/2020 WeekOf: 3 WeekNumber: 2 ***
Date: 14/01/2020 WeekOf: 3 WeekNumber: 2 ***
Date: 20/01/2020 WeekOf: 4 WeekNumber: 3 ***
Date: 21/01/2020 WeekOf: 4 WeekNumber: 3 ***
Date: 27/01/2020 WeekOf: 5 WeekNumber: 4 ***
Date: 28/01/2020 WeekOf: 5 WeekNumber: 4 ***
Date: 03/02/2020 WeekOf: 6 WeekNumber: 5 ***
Date: 04/02/2020 WeekOf: 6 WeekNumber: 5 ***
Date: 10/02/2020 WeekOf: 7 WeekNumber: 6 ***
```

As you can see, things start going wrong at the end of 2018 and, after that,
the erroneous values seem to suggest an "off by one" kind of error.  I leave
you to investigate and fix this problem yourself.

The reason I haven't looked into it any further myself is that it seems to me
that the way you are doing it is messy and avoidably complicated.  It is virtually trivial to add week number
support to your RBuilder reports by adding a calculated field with the weeknumber
value to the dataset which feeds the report.  Code to do that is shown below.

Alternatively, you could use ReportBuilder's facility to add a `WeekNumber`
function to the RAP run-time language that can take any datetime value (e.g.
a value from any dataset datetime field).  See e.g. `Extending RAP - RAP Pass-Through Functions` at p213 of the ReportBuilder Developer's guide available
here: [Report Builder Developer's Guide](http://www.digital-metaphors.com/download/pdf/RBuilder.pdf).  What is described
there is probably the most flexible method of surfacing a Delphi function
in a report, though ISTR there are others.

Code (excluding RBuilder components for simplicity)

```
  type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
      CDS1: TClientDataSet;
      DataSource1: TDataSource;
      DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
      DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
      procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      procedure CDS1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
    private
      procedure CreateDataSetFields;
    protected
    public
    end;
  [...]
  implementation
  uses
    DateUtils;

  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var
    i : Integer;
  begin
    CreateDataSetFields;  // see below
    CDS1.CreateDataSet;

    //  Insert one row per day for current year
    for i := 1 to 365 do begin
      CDS1.InsertRecord([i, i + Now - DayOfTheYear(Now)]);
    end;
    CDS1.First;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.CDS1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
  begin
    //  This sets the WeekNo calculated field to the value returned by the DateUtils.WeekOf function
    DataSet.FieldByName('WeekNo').AsInteger := WeekOf(DataSet.FieldByName('Date').AsDateTime);
  end;

  procedure TForm1.CreateDataSetFields;
  var
    Field : TField;
  begin
    Field := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
    Field.FieldKind := fkData;
    Field.FieldName := 'ID';
    Field.Name := 'ID';
    Field.DataSet := CDS1;

    Field := TDateTimeField.Create(Self);
    Field.FieldKind := fkData;
    Field.FieldName := 'Date';
    Field.Name := 'Date';
    Field.DataSet := CDS1;

    Field := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
    Field.FieldKind := fkInternalCalc;
    Field.FieldName := 'WeekNo';
    Field.Name := 'WeekNo';
    Field.DataSet := CDS1;
  end;
```

Comment: I hope that this has shown you how to check your RAP code against delphi code AND how to avoid the need to calculate the week number yourself by using Delphi's `WeekOf` function to populate a calculated dataset field.  Has either of these solved your problem?

Comment: A lot of effort has obviously gone into this answer.  Why don't you accept it?